# Spring Boot Resource server fails to authenticate my token

Tags: spring, azure, security, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am a beginner in Spring outh2 security. I was trying to secure my spring boot rest api's and run them in postman ,
But I always get the "*Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Signed JWT rejected: Invalid signature", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"*" error.

Note:- I am using Azure AD as an authorization server.

Steps followed .

1. Implemented the below code in STS and ran the application.
2. Created a access token using the postman "Get New Access Token" using Client Credentials Auth type.
3. Use that access token and call my spring boot api using Get request.

Note: - When I copy my postman generated token in jwt.io I get a Invalid Signature at the bottom ..but I am able to read the header /payload.

But when I switch the algorithm to HS256 , I don't get an Invalid signature any more.

[screenshot of postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiD4L.png)
Below is my basic code.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>resourceserver</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>resourceserver</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My application.properties

```
server.port=8090
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=https://sts.windows.net/tenenentid
```

Tried using this url as well , but no luck.

spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenentid

Basic Rest api.

```
@GetMapping("/validateApi")
public String validateApi() {
    
    
    System.out.println("validateApi");
    return "invalid";
}
```

Not sure if I am missing on any other additional steps. I have not customized any security config as such.  So I am assuming it just uses the default configs.

Any help will be appreciated .

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I generated the access token using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token



client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

***When I decoded the token, I got the same error as below:***

[image]

> **Note**  that: The token generated for Graph doesn't require validation and it will not verify signature in the code.

**Alternatively**, to resolve the error you can Expose an API in the Portal like below:

[image]

I generated the access token with the  **scope**  as  `api://ClientIDofApp/.default`  :

[image]

**The signature got verified successfully like below:**

[image]